# How can I set my view to the whole frame?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am making a game in swift. I was wondering how I could fix the problem where the view of my scene does not match of with the Scene's frame.

To be more specific, I want to be able to make an edge physics body around the screen so that nothing can escape the outside of the screen. In GameScene I put `self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)`.

But this has the weird effect of covering a larger area than what I view at one time. If someone could help with this, I would be very appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: are you using an sks file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Since I was loading the GameScene from a file, the size was off a little bit. I changed the size of the scene in GameScene.sks and my program works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using scale mode .AspectFill, maybe one part of your scene is outside seeable area of view controller then SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame) did not work as you expected.

try `self.view.frame` instead of `self.frame` (and maybe you will have to multiply with 2 if your device comes with rentina display)

Comment: Yes, I am using .AspectFill. I tried `self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.view.frame)`, but XCode 6 gave me the error `'SKView?' does not have a member named 'frame'`

Comment: try `self.view.bounds`

Comment: You can add character "!" after view (read about "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals" of Swift): 'let viewFrame = self.view!.frame;'

Comment: What would I multiply by 2?

Comment: becoz view.frame size is in point, but physicsbody size is in pixel and with rentina display, 1 point = 2 pixel. I'm not sure, just test and correct me if I'm wrong